# Zend Framework - Error when URL has $$$ or ~ on controller/action segment

Tags: zend-framework, url

In our ZF based site, if a url contains `$$$` or `~` on the controller/action segment, it was not caught as 404 error, instead, they landed on the controller/action without the symbol, but when it tries to load the view script, the view script file is still having those symbol thus causing an error.

For example:

```
site.com/index$$$
script 'index$$$/index.phtml' not found in path

site.com/index-$$$
script 'index-$$$/index.phtml' not found in path

site.com/index~
script 'index~/index.phtml' not found in path 

site.com/index/index~
script 'index/index~.phtml' not found in path
```

They must be caught as 404 error and out site can catch 404 errors if the controller/action is non existing.

```
ex: /badurl$$$, /non/existing~
```

Example: http://framework.zend.com/index.$$$/index~

Is there any existing issues / solutions to this?

Thanks in advance!

PS: we are still using ZF 1.0.3 but this also affects other sites which are in 1.8.2.

**Update:** This is the content of .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/search$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule . /search/?%1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect all https urls to http
# These are the pages excluded on the redirection
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/minify/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/myaccount/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/akamai/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/navigation/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cache/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/includes/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pdf/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

######################################################

# if non-PHP file is requested, display the file #
RewriteRule \.(js|ico|txt|gif|jpg|png|css|xml|swf|zip|pdf|gz)$ - [L,NC]

# if PHP file is requested and it exists, display the file #
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule \.php$ - [L]

# redirect everything else to controller #
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/server-status.*
RewriteRule .+$ index.php [L]

# Disable Etags
    FileETag none
```

Comment: What are your rewrite rules? ZF 1.0.3? Damn.

Comment: Updated post to include rewrite rules.

Comment: I re-read your post. If the controller is being called correctly, but the view script isn't, it sounds like your PHP is actually wrong. How are you setting the view script path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in your .htaccess file.

Your problem is originating in the dispatcher see the protected method in 1.0.3 [`Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Abstract::_formatName()`](http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/tags/release-1.0.3/library/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Abstract.php). This method hasn't changed since 1.0.3 either. So, an upgrade won't help.

It's actually removing all the special characters from the URI using `preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9 ]/', '', $segment)` and returning a valid class name.

Without writing your own custom dispatcher, you will have to use different naming with alphanumeric characters i.e. /xxx or /000

See Method Below:

```
 /**
 * Formats a string from a URI into a PHP-friendly name.
 *
 * By default, replaces words separated by the word separator character(s)
 * with camelCaps. If $isAction is false, it also preserves replaces words
 * separated by the path separation character with an underscore, making
 * the following word Title cased. All non-alphanumeric characters are
 * removed.
 *
 * @param string $unformatted
 * @param boolean $isAction Defaults to false
 * @return string
 */
protected function _formatName($unformatted, $isAction = false)
{
    // preserve directories
    if (!$isAction) {
        $segments = explode($this->getPathDelimiter(), $unformatted);
    } else {
        $segments = (array) $unformatted;
    }

    foreach ($segments as $key => $segment) {
        $segment        = str_replace($this->getWordDelimiter(), ' ', strtolower($segment));
        $segment        = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9 ]/', '', $segment);
        $segments[$key] = str_replace(' ', '', ucwords($segment));
    }

    return implode('_', $segments);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the very good find. Will try to see if our codes can be patched for this.

Comment: Would it be save it I just put some redirection rules like this?   80 # Disallow wierd url fragments to cause app in 500 error due to ZF weird namne formatting  
 81 RewriteRule ^.+[^-a-zA-Z0-9_/]$ /404.html [R=301,L]  
 82 RewriteRule ^.+[^-a-zA-Z0-9_]/.+$ /404.html [R=301,L]

Comment: I think your idea to use the rewrite rule to catch invalid requests is just fine. Just be careful of other filenames like images, js, css, etc.